# Adding @media directly into element?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Oke here's the problem.
Im making a webshop with online software. On the pages i can use html/css/javascript but i can only edit the body part of the page. I cannot access the style.css file or the head to add my own style.

Now i know that i can edit some things by using for example p style="color: red;"  but i am wondering if i can use "@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)" the same way?

I want to change the width of a table below 768px without the css file or access to the head of the page. Is this possible?

Comment: If you can edit the body, can you add an inline `<style />` tag? Because if you can you can use `@media` in there.

Comment: You could insert a `style` tag with the css you want in the html.

Comment: it seems that it doesnt accept <style>

Answer (score 0):

No.

Only `property: value` pairs can be assigned using the style attribute.